# Structure element declarations

Tags: c++, struct

```
{
    WORD    test1:12;
    WORD    test2:4;
}
```

I found a snippet with the following code in the structure and I was wondering what does the `:12` and `:4` exactly mean?

Comment: those are bit fields.

Comment: If `WORD` is a signed integral type, then `test1` and `test2` will be signed as well, otherwise all unsigned.  The numbers that can be stored are as you'd expect: -2^11..2^11-1 and -2^4..2^4-1 for signed, 0..2^12-1 and ..2^4-1 for unsigned.  How they're packed into the structure is implementation defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are bit fields. 
Classes and structures can contain members that occupy less storage than an integral type. These members are specified as bit fields. The syntax for bit-field member-declarator specification follows:

`declarator  : constant-expression`

For more details, go to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/bit_field

Answer (score 1):

Those are bit fields. Above structure declaration tells that test1 will occupy 12 bits and test2 will occupy 4 bits.

Check the link for a practical example - http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/C/node13.html